# UI frozen while populating TreeView

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, c#-2.0

What can be wrong with Windows Forms method. It's ran by separate, non-UI thread, but still freezes the application UI for 10 seconds when I have 100 000 treeNodes to add.

```
private static void FillNodes(TreeView treeView, TreeNode[] nodes)
{
    if (treeView.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action<TreeView, TreeNode[]> action = FillNodes;
        treeView.BeginInvoke(action, treeView, nodes);
    }
    else
    {
        treeView.SuspendLayout();
        treeView.BeginUpdate();
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
        treeView.Sort();
        treeView.EndUpdate();
        treeView.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: `treeView.BeginInvoke` is calling `FillNodes` on the UI thread. You either need to determine which nodes the user is looking at and only draw those, or [virtualize your `treeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Adding 100000 nodes to TreeView makes the UI thread too busy, no matter you use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` as they also run/schedule to run the code in UI thread. It is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 100000 nodes to TreeView makes the UI thread too busy, no matter you use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` as they also run the code in UI thread. It is what it is.

In general it's definitely a bad idea to show 100000 nodes in TreeView. To show that amount of nodes in a tree, it would be much better if you load and add the nodes lazily. The idea is loading the root first level of nodes and adding dummy children to them, then handing `BeforeExpand` to load the real children and adding to nodes (and again adding dummy children to this level).

But anyhow, for those who may want to load that amount of node and make the loading experience a bit smoother, consider the following facts (I see you have considered these point in your code):

- When you call `treeView.BeginInvoke` or `treeView.Invoke` it actually runs in UI thread, so if you do a heavy lifting there, it blocks the thread for a while.
- Calling `BeginUpdate` before changing the tree nodes and calling `EndUpdate` prevents a lot of painting and makes the load smoother.
- Using `AddRange` (which doesn't need BeginUpdate and EndUpdate), make loading the tree much faster.

So you can:

- Load data in another thread (not the UI thread) (or use async await if possible)
- Create an array of nodes in the other thread
- Add the nodes using `AddRange` in the UI thread. (If you use async/await no Invoke is required, but using threads or BackgroundWorker, Invoke is required.)

For example:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodes = await GetNodes();
    treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
}
public async Task<TreeNode[]> GetNodes()
{
    //Get data asynchronously from db or weherever it is
    //Create nodes
    //Return nodes

    //Just for example:
    return await Task.Run<TreeNode[]>(() =>
        Enumerable.Range(1, 100000)
            .Select(x => new TreeNode(x.ToString())).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Same for `Task` and async/await, but as it's already mentioned,... `//Just for example:`

Comment: I understand it's an example, but perhaps suggesting a feature OP does have access to in their version of C# might be more helpful. For example: `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: I agree, but the point is just in `AddRange` :)

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: Well, I noticed the OP has already applied all the points. The final note is: Adding 100000 nodes to TreeView makes the UI thread too busy, no matter you use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` as they also run/schedule to run the code in UI thread. *It is what it is.*

Comment: Honestly I tried everything (backgoundworker, async/await etc.)  - it doesn't matter. It behaves differently but always freezes the UI. I created TreeNodes[] since beginning in separate thread (this takes about 10s in my case). Then in this thread I have to call AddRange (I did it since the beginning) but I also secured accessing the UI by InvokeRequired.... but it also doesn't help. When I call AddRange inside non-UI thread tthe thread finishes correctly, but the TreeView remains frozen when the thread calling AddRange finishes it's work.

Comment: It looks like when the treeView get's back to be paited by UI thread it requires additional 5-8 seconds to draw a tree. It doesn't help even when I call Refresh in secured by InvokeRequired block.

Comment: Btw. I knew about the solution with painting only needed nodes (I did it in the past) but in this case it's not an option (DataGidView as well).

Comment: @SebastianKokoszko Thanks for your feedback  on the answer, my conclusion is the first line of the answer (unfortunately). You definitely know your requirements better, but for very large trees, I've always used lazy loading.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - thank you very much for your answer. It seems that simply it cannot be done the way which I expected.